# How can I add a space inside a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with two fixed elements at the bottom of my page:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom-element {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#notifications {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
      overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.entry {
  padding: 15px;
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="title">Notifications</div>
  <div id="notifications">
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-element"></div>
```

The problem is that the last entry is hidden under `bottom-element`. I've already tried this on the notifications element:

- `padding-bottom: 30px`
- `margin-bottom: 30px`

And also a pseudo element:

```
#notifications::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

But nothing works. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want, I'll go with the quickest one.

**The reason you didn't get what you expected:**
Your bottom bar is outside and isn't constrained by your wrapper and the wrapper isn't restricted to 100% height (the viewport of the screen that you're using), so the notifications section just takes more space below. Since your bottom-bar is fixed at the bottom it will overlap.
You will see fewer than six notification on a small screen.

**How to fix:**
 - Move the bottom bar inside your wrapper
 - Make your wrapper flex with column direction
 - Give it 100% height

Now your notifications can be scrolled and viewed, and this will work even if you have 10's or 100's of notifications.

**Why this worked:**
Your wrapper is now 100% and cannot go below the screen. It's flex, so the elements inside wrapper - 'title', 'notifications' and 'bottom-element' will adjust and fit themselves nicely. Plus your notifications has an overflow scroll so any extra notifications will be hidden but visible on scrolling down.

Updated snippet with fix:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#bottom-element {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#notifications {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.entry {
  padding: 15px;
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="title">Notifications</div>
  <div id="notifications">
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to insert a non-breaking space. Second, you insert white space of different widths. After that, you mimic a tab with non-breaking spaces. Now you can indent paragraphs with CSS.